# ...the House with Chimeras, as Gorodetsky House is also known, was

Tags: parts-of-speech

This is from [a *Los Angeles Times* article](https://www.latimes.com/entertainment-arts/story/2022-02-28/how-volodymyr-zelenksy-uses-kyiv-gorodetsky-house-on-social-media?fbclid=IwAR16T2w3Ea3zdby5njyqZMBnbIKwoVpoS-QOwCqxqSfBaMRcOyC5SrpiwHQ).

> After a needed renovation in 2004, the House with Chimeras, **as
> Gorodetsky House is also known** (in reference to the architectural
> term describing gargoyle-style decorations on a facade), was
> transformed into an official government building.

I think the part in bold could be changed to 'also known as Gorodetsky House'.

Is the 'as' in bold a conjuction or a preposition?

Comment: The way the sentence is written implies that Gorodetsky House is the usual name of the building and 'The House with Chimeras' an alternative. Your version doesn't; in fact, it might suggest that it's the other way round.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @KateBunting How about 'as which Gorodetsky House is also known'?

Comment: The _which_ is unnecessary, since the meaning is conveyed perfectly well without it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you asking about the word "as" or whether your rewording is correct?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct! "*also known as Gorodetsky House*" would be perfectly fine and, IMO, is a better word order.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, happy to help :)